# Can we give value inside input element which type is number?

Tags: php, html

When I give the value then an error occurs. In profile page I want to display mobile number in value inside number input element.mobile number is display but in html section error display. The error is bad value for attribute value on element input.

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo $profileinfo[0]['mobile_number']; ?>" name="profile[mobileno]" pattern="^\d{10}$" required title="format : xxxxxxxxxx">
```

Comment: might be, that your $profileinfo[0]['mobile_number'] does not match the used pattern. maybe you do have some spaces in it, try to cast to int.

Comment: what is your mobile number in input? Can you please tell here?

Comment: using register form i get the mobile number in database.in the register form  <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter yor mobile no(format: xxxxxxxxxx)" name="register[mobileno]" pattern="^\d{10}$"  required title="format : xxxxxxxxxx">

Comment: Fix some orthography

Comment: Convert value to the number format and try. - 
number_format($profileinfo[0]['mobile_number'])